# Rack::QueryParser::InvalidParameterError (Invalid encoding for parameter: f�u6�]��S��7��&A�y��):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to make a torrent tracker in Ruby On Rails but when the torrent client connects to my application it gives HTTP response code 400 (Bad Request). This is what appears on the console

```
Started GET "/announce?info_hash=f%e5u6%ac%5d%df%c8S%fc%9c7%b3%ff%26A%c3y%85%a3&peer_id=-TR2840-tgshmuspym9s&port=51413&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=11675&numwant=0&key=1a314ff6&compact=1&supportcrypto=1&event=stopped" for 10.30.45.9 at 2018-07-22 01:02:39 -0400

Rack::QueryParser::InvalidParameterError (Invalid encoding for parameter: f�u6�]��S��7��&A�y��):
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your URL contains special characters, try to [url_encode](https://apidock.com/ruby/ERB/Util/url_encode) before calling the API:

```
require 'uri'
uri = "/announce?info_hash=f%e5u6%ac%5d%df%c8S%fc%9c7%b3%ff%26A%c3y%85%a3&peer_id=-TR2840-tgshmuspym9s&port=51413&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=11675&numwant=0&key=1a314ff6&compact=1&supportcrypto=1&event=stopped"
url = URI.parse(URI::encode(uri))
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm using RubyOnRails, how can I do it??

Comment: If you share your code snippet related to how your app connects to torrent client, then we can help better.

Comment: I just create a new project, create a controller named torrent with an action named announce, I edit the routes.rb and I add " get 'announce' => 'torrent#announce' "